# connection to web sever and request a document

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I have already tried it using telnet and python script but still, its showing HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

```
import socket
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysocket.connect(('data.pr4e.org',80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/intro-short.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
mysocket.send(cmd)
while True:
    data = mysocket.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysocket.close()
```

Comment: Don't forget that the HTTP newline is `'\r\n'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with requests you can easily get that doc:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests


def main():
    r = requests.get('http://data.pr4e.org/intro-short.txt')
    print(r.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Not sure if this is a valid solution for you.
source: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/